# db2 update multiple field for a record

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with 1 row and 2 columns: col1 and col2,

```
--------------------------------------------------
|     col1          |        col2                |
--------------------------------------------------
|       1           |         2                  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

now I want to update the row record:

```
db2 "update myschema.mytable set col1=3, col2=col1"
```

I expect the result to be `col1=3` and `col2=3`, but it gives me `col1=3`,`col2=1`

how do I update one column base on a newly updated column?

Comment: Change the order of columns in the `SET` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @A INT
SELECT @A = Col1 FROM Mytable
UPDATE MyTable SET Col1 = 4, Col2 = @A
```